# AWK based on row name and export the following 3 and 4 rows

Tags: awk, grep

I have tab delimited .txt files looking like this:

```
""
"5 um"
"Lipid droplet number"
"Lipid droplet diameter"
"Mito"
22
0
5 um
64 255 0 0
2
1615 2022
2037 2021
1
Lipid droplet number
64 255 0 0
1
583 1945
0
Lipid droplet diameter
64 255 0 0
2
1406 849
1364 882
0
Lipid droplet diameter
64 255 0 0
2
1105 1333
1082 1369
0
Lipid droplet diameter
64 255 0 0
2
619 1932
580 1953
0
```

I want to make a new .txt files including only the 2nd and 3rd row following all places with rowname "Lipid droplet diameter".

The result should be something like this: (I want to delete all other rows than with those with diameter info)

```
1406 849
1364 882
1105 1333
1082 1369
619 1932
580 1953
```

2 columns and 2 rows is ok.
4 columns and 1 row is also ok. This one is best for Excel I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/Lipid droplet diameter/{n;n;n;N;p}' input
```

Gives:

```
1406 849
1364 882
1105 1333
1082 1369
619 1932
580 1953
```

Another method:

```
grep -A 4 'Lipid droplet diameter' input | sed -n '/--/!p' | \ 
    awk ' (NR-1)%5>2 { print }'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get: "sed: 1: "/Lipid droplet diameter ...": extra characters at the end of p command"

Comment: OSX 10.8.4. Here It is: sed -n '/Lipid droplet diameter/{n;n;n;N;p}' /Users/sindrelee/Documents/LD_diameter/Acute_Exercise/Analysis\#2887_Tv11.tif.txt > /Users/sindrelee/Documents/LD_diameter/Acute_Exercise_AWK/test.txt

Comment: I pasted in what really is on the first rows in the file (look at first post), maybe it has an effect?

Comment: @user2862862, added another method

Comment: Works fantastic!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

An ugly getline awk

```
awk '/diameter/ {getline;getline;getline;a=a?a" "$0:$0;getline;b=b?b" "$0:$0} END {print a"\n"b}' file
1406 849 1105 1333 619 1932
1364 882 1082 1369 580 1953
```

---

A better version

```
awk '/diameter/ {f=NR} f && f+3==NR {a=a?a" "$0:$0} f && f+4==NR {b=b?b" "$0:$0} END {print a"\n"b}' file
1406 849 1105 1333 619 1932
1364 882 1082 1369 580 1953
```

---

Better table view:

```
awk '/diameter/ {f=NR} f && f+3==NR {a=a?a"\t"$0:$0} f && f+4==NR {b=b?b"\t"$0:$0} END {print "Column1\t\tColumn2\t\tColumn3\n" a"\n"b}' file
Column1         Column2         Column3
1406 849        1105 1333       619 1932
1364 882        1082 1369       580 1953
```

Comment: What 3 first rows?  It does not print `row1=Lipid droplet number` nor `row2=64 255 0 0` or `row3=1`

Comment: My bad, I did not post the first 3 rows, I thought it was a simple extra add-on.. The original file has 3 rows, which I dont want. I have updated it.

Comment: And this command does not produce the output as is written here. Its a double tab in the print line. Also the rows is not moved to the columns..

Answer (score 1):

For variable rows and columns, you could try this:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"; SUBSEP="@"; MAXROWS=1000
}

/^Lipid droplet diameter$/ {
    cols++; rows=0
    while (NF != 2) getline
    while (NF == 2 && rows < MAXROWS) {
        vectors[cols, ++rows] = $0
        getline
    }
}

END {
    for (c = 1; c <= cols; c++) printf("Column%i%c", c, c<cols ? OFS : "\n")
    for (r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
        for (c = 1; c <= cols; c++) printf("%s%c", vectors[c, r], c<cols ? OFS : "\n")
    }
}
```

Example assuming the above is saved as `lipid.awk`:

```
awk -f lipid.awk input
```

Comment: Thanks man, but I dont understand your script.. :/ Anyways, I entered the desired output wrong! I had to do it another way for usage in Excel.

Comment: user2862862, does the added example help?

Comment: I missed that the desired output has changed.