# AWK half of rows to a new column

Tags: awk, grep

I run this command:

```
awk '/diameter/ {f=NR} f && f+3==NR {a=a?a$0:$0} f && f+4==NR {b=b?b$0:$0} END {print a"\n"b}' file > output
```

Output (the file I want to change):

```
5 um  
1406 849  
1105 1333  
619 1932  
1885 124  
571 374  
145 644  
1487 1793  
64 255 0 0  
1364 882  
1082 1369  
580 1953  
1886 124  
536 392  
126 659  
1488 1793
```

But I want it to look like this (half of the rows moved to column 2).

```
1406 849    1364 882  
1105 1333   1082 1369  
619 1932    580 1953  
1885 124    1886 124  
571 374 536 392  
145 644 126 659  
1487 1793   1488 1793
```

One column should include two numbers. I also want to DELETE "`5 um 64 255 0 0`"

Comment: One column should include two numbers. I also want to DELETE "5 um 64 255 0 0"

Comment: You need to post the `file` for us to help.

Comment: My file is the one after the AWK command, I have updated the command and output file.

Comment: You are showing the output of an `awk` command.  We ask you for posting the `file` content, not just the location of the name in the awk command.

Answer (score 1):

`pr` is your friend to do such thing:

(ignore the header `column1 column2`):

```
pr -2t -s' ' file|grep -v '[^0-9 \t]'
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
5 um
1406 849
1105 1333
619 1932
1885 124
571 374
145 644
1487 1793
64 255 0 0
1364 882
1082 1369
580 1953
1886 124
536 392
126 659
1488 1793

kent$  pr -2t -s' '  f|grep -v '[^0-9 \t]'
1406 849 1364 882
1105 1333 1082 1369
619 1932 580 1953
1885 124 1886 124
571 374 536 392
145 644 126 659
1487 1793 1488 1793
```

Comment: Very nice! But its not always at the 9th row I must move to a new column, its always the half of the total number of rows.

Comment: @user2862862 it is not always on row 9. I even didn't know it was line 9. `pr` just does it for me.

Comment: I get an empty output.. Whats wired I dont get the same output from the "cat" command as you, row 1-7 is missing..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work out (`bash` code, assuming your input is in `file.txt`):

```
(( nlines = $(wc -l < file.txt) / 2 ))
split -l ${nlines} -d -a 1 file.txt foo
paste foo0 foo1 > output.txt
rm foo0 foo1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found out I needed another output. I have made a new thread and flagged this one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835998/awk-based-on-row-name-and-export-the-following-3-and-4-rows